# Can't access my drives from open suse 12.3

Tags: linux, opensuse

I just installed linux along with my Windows 7 in separate drives. Now when I try to access hard drives from linux it shows error as:

> An error occurred while accessing 'Home',the system responded: An
>   unspecified error has occurred: Not authorized to perform operation.

Any Idea?  Suggestions?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92425/13792